# The best way to see AWS Autoscaling Group EC2 Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to see the metrics like CPU utilization of EC2 instances in ASG. As I see on ASG -> Metrics -> EC2 there are some metrics, but is not clear is it measured per instance or some average value?
What is the best way to see instances state in ASG i.e. CPU or memory?

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_PredefinedMetricSpecification.html), autoscaling average values are available:

> ASGAverageCPUUtilization - average CPU utilization of the Auto Scaling
>   group

Since you only see one value it is most likely to be the average value.

Now to answer your question whether it is better to scale based on CPU or memory, there is no magic formula and you should be load testing a single instance first to determine which one is the limiting factor. **ab** (Apache Bench) and **[vegeta](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta)** are both great load testing tool for web applications.

And note that by default memory metric does not get pushed to cloudwatch so you will need to setup a custom tool for that.

Comment: in my case I have created 2 instances inside of ASG, but still have one graph for CPU. As for metrics obviously it is better to check both, the question is what is the best way to set it up, because on ASG Metrics it seems like it is not possible to see per instance metrics for instances added dynamically.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake regarding the metric. I updated my answer to your scaling issue as it was unclear in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for my case which is having similar architecture.
I am using application load balancer, so I am scaling on request count per target.
So now question is How I decided what is optimal request count per target? 
I ran load test and trying to find at what request count my EC2 is starting to break. Depending on my findings from my load test I have calculated my optimal Request Count and added that in my ASG scaling policy.